# JTextArea - how to get first index of current line?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Suppose I have a `JTextArea` and I want to replace current line with a specific text:

**Example**

```
123
123455
68967869
gh
```

Now I want to replace text of current cursor existing line.

So if cursor in the 3rd line, output will be:

```
123
123455
replaced text
gh
```

Now I have this code. But it just append to current line not to the fist position of current line.

```
 jtextarea1.getDocument().insertString(jtextarea1.getCaretPosition(), "replaced text", null);
```

**Output**

```
123
123455
68967869replaced text//that's the problem
gh
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) APIs:

```
JTextArea txt = ...;
int caretOffset = txt.getCaretPosition();
int lineNumber = txt.getLineOfOffset(caretOffset);
int startOffset = txt.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
int endOffset = txt.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);

txt.replaceRange("Replaced Text", startOffset, endOffset);
```

Comment: Why not link to [`JTextArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) (latest docs)?

Comment: @whiletrue Fixed the mistake.

Comment: *"this gives me error"*  A `TooManyKittensError`?  Spay the tom-cat.  (Always copy/paste error and exception output!)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yeah sure. That's what I got when I googled `JTextArea` ;)

Comment: *"That's what I got when I googled.."*  Yep.  Familiar with that experience.  When it drops me into the earlier docs, I experiment by changing the number to latest docs and see if it works.  If it does, that's the one that is pasted (otherwise I just hit the back button and take the one that works ;) ).